# Same baseline for independent paragraphs with different font-size

Tags: html, css, alignment, typography

Basically I want to align both lines to appear on the same line, but I really have no idea how to do this properly. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6oycxe4/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="first">
  <p>
    Lorem<br/>
    ipsum<br/>
    dolor<br/>
    sit<br/>
    amet
  </p>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <p>Align</p>
  <p>Multi</p>
  <p>
    Lines<br/>
    And<br/>
    Paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  float: left;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.first {
  font-size: 17px;

  //...
  width: 50px;
}

.second {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `display` attribute to align the two DIVs side by side, this is a very basic example. The `margin-right: -4px` is to fix a rendering bug in some browsers where the two DIVs of 50% width in this case won't align properly beside each other.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marvzjh1/)

```
div {
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.second {
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want two columns. My solution for that is as follows:

CSS:

```
.two-col {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
          column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5rem;
       -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
            column-gap: 1.5rem
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="two-col">
  <p>
    Lorem<br/>
    ipsum<br/>
    dolor<br/>
    sit<br/>
    amet
  </p>
  <p>Align</p>
  <p>Multi</p>
  <p>
    Lines<br/>
    And<br/>
    Paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

Of course you will need to adjust according to your needs regarding column gap. etc.